# Docker compose bitcoin service

Tags: docker, docker-compose, bitcoin, bitcoind

I have a simple python service that sends a single command to a running bitcoin server. When I run a local bitcoin daemon everything works fine. However, when I try to run this using `Docker` I cannot connect this service to a bitcoin server in another docker image, like in this `docker-compose`:

```
version: '3'
services:
  my_service:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    depends_on:
      - bitcoind
    links:
      - bitcoind
    working_dir: /app

  bitcoind:
    image: ruimarinho/bitcoin-core:0.15.0.1-alpine
    command:
      -printtoconsole
      -regtest=1
      -rest
      -rpcallowip=10.211.0.0/16
      -rpcallowip=172.17.0.0/16
      -rpcallowip=192.168.0.0/16
      -rpcpassword=bar
      -rpcport=18333
      -rpcuser=foo
      -server
    ports:
      - 18333:18333

volumes:
  bitcoin_data:
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='bitcoind', port=18333): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7faded979310>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',))
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Enter the bitcoind container and check if the 18333 port is opened and the service is running.

Comment: What’s the ENTRYPOINT of your service? How is it trying to connect (e.g. connection string)? Also, ref. the rpcallowip settings, are you certain you’re connecting from one of those CIDR ranges (don’t see any docker network configuration settings - what’s the IP of the running container) - have tried to rpcallowip=0.0.0.0?

Answer (score 0):

You must open the container port 18333. With the docker compose, you can use the command 'expose' to do it.